# 360-degree photo viewer and managment library for Android Java

Tags: android, 360-degrees, 360-panorama

What I want to do is this:

Ability to add ImageView or Button elements on top of a 360-degree photo and their location fixed.
Example scenario:
There is a 360 degree photo of the kitchen. I added buttons on the light bulbs in the kitchen. Even if the photo rotates left and right, that button should always stay on the bulb.

Which library can I do this with?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or URL of the type of thing you're looking to replicate? That would help understand your goal.

Comment: I tried to do the thing I mentioned with the hannesa2/panoramaGL library available on github. Everything looks good, but I can't give a click event to the hotspot buttons that we put on the panoramic photo and the library has no developer documentation. If anyone has other library suggestions for android, I'm waiting for your suggestions. Or I can open a new question about giving click events to hotspot buttons in this library.

VIDEO:
[link]https://streamable.com/hezh34